# Magento 2: How to submit form on checkbox click?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, forms

Can someone help me?

I need to know how to send the form `checkout/cart/updatePost` when clicking on a checkbox. It should include an input field hidden or similar with the `name=udpate_cart_action` and a value.

When we pulse on:

[image: Update Shopping Cart button]

```
<button type="submit"
    name="update_cart_action"
    data-cart-item-update=""
    value="update_qty"
    title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Update Shopping Cart')); ?>" class="action update">
     <span>
          <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Update Shopping Cart'); ?>
     </span>
</button>
```

We send a param in the request object with the name and value.

But I don't if I must to send this name and value with the checkbox or in the JavaScript...

I have this input type checkbox **foreach** item

```
<input id="item_<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($itemId) ?>" name="item[check][<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($itemId) ?>]"  type="checkbox" class="check_item" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($itemId) ?>"
```

And this code javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".check_item").on("change", ":checkbox", function() {
            console.log("check");
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I pulse on checkbox and it's status change nothing happens :-(

***UPDATE***

Thanks, [Philipp Sander](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/34273/philipp-sander) your answer was correct. The problem was to add

> require(['jquery'], function ($){ //code ]);

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {

        $(".check_item").change(function() {
            if(this.checked) {
                $("#update_baa").click();
            } else {

                $("#update_baa").click();
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".check_item").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Philipp but not work. In Safari debug console I have this error "TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$(".check_item")', '$' is undefined)"

Comment: I change $ to jQuery and do not work neither

Comment: well there you have it